# .append something that is .load -ed with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, load, append

I have a webpage like:

```
<html>
<head>
   . . .
</head>
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <p>Lots of content here!</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I also have an external file like this:

```
<div id="more-stuff"><p>Even more content!</p></div>
```

What I want is for to have a webpage like this:

```
<html>
<head>
   . . .
</head>
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <p>Lots of content here!</p>
    <div id="more-stuff"><p>Even more content!</p></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Using jQuery. My guess is something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#wrapper').append.load('/external.htm');
});
```

But it won't work and I can't seem to find a good solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.get('/external.htm', function(data) {
        $('#wrapper').append(data);
    });
});
```

It tells jQuery to request the html file, and then to run the callback (which in turn appends the data returned by the request) when it is ready.

Comment: Is there any reason why this is a better solution than the next one?

Comment: Indeed, I missed a ); - fixed. The only difference between this example and the next one is that the next one will wrap the contents of external.htm in a *p* tag (so it will be `<p><div id="more-stuff"><p>Even more content!</p></div></p>`) while this one will just add the contents without wrapping.

Answer (score 1):

`.append()` doesn't work that way. It needs text to append. But `.load()` overwrites the contents of its target, so you need to first append a child, then load to that child.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#wrapper').append($(document.createElement("p")).load('extern.html'));
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. It works. I now realize why my version didn't work. I'm curious, do you know of any reason this solution is better than the previous one?

Comment: Well, instead of answering whether it's better or worse, I'll tell you that my answer is synchronous, whereas rsp's answer is asynchronous. The async answer could allow the entire page to load faster, but it could also result in a "FOUC" or "Flash of Un(finished) Content". Unless you're dealing with network problems or really big files, it probably doesn't matter.

Comment: actually your example is also asynchronous. `$('selector').load(url);` is pretty much a shortcut for `$.get(url, function (data) { $('selector').html(data); });`